# ActionController::UnknownFormat Error In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Whenever I try to create a new Post, I get this error.

> ActionController::UnknownFormat Error In Rails

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |f|
      if(@post.save)
        f.html  {redirect_to "", notice: "Post Created!"}
      else 
        # f.html {redirect_to "", notice: "Error! Post not saved"}
      end
    end
  end

  private 

  def post_params #allows certain data to be passed via post form
    params.require(:post).permit(:user_id, :create)
  end
end
```

Rails is telling me that the error happens in the respond_to block on line 15.

This is what the Rails server says:

> Started POST "/posts" for 24.188.104.188 at 2017-07-30 03:57:59 +0000 Cannot render console from 24.188.104.188! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255 Processing by PostsController#create as HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"+0rkRgEUi9BvIgLyRyxh7wr3VVr5F3HpgoMQVKcwrTmn9tNB6xkKNx+EpxPt7l0NA4sv/lsjmwjn0ROh1gre4A==",
>   "post"=>{"content"=>"hohoh"}, "commit"=>"Add Post"} Unpermitted
>   parameter: content   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"
>   WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
>   (0.1ms)  begin transaction    (0.1ms)  rollback transaction Redirected
>   to https://bump-jshariar.c9users.io Completed 302 Found in 21ms
>   (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
>
> Started GET "/" for 24.188.104.188 at 2017-07-30 03:57:59 +0000 Cannot
>   render console from 24.188.104.188! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1,
>   127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255 Processing by PagesController#index as HTML   Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
>   User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" =
>   ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]   Rendered
>   layouts/_nav_user.html.erb (0.3ms)   Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb
>   (2.0ms) Completed 200 OK in 73ms (Views: 72.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)

Answer (score -1):

It worked with:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |f|
      if(@post.save)
        f.html  { redirect_to "", notice: "Post Created!" }
      else 
        # f.html { redirect_to '' }
      end
    end
  end

  private 

  def post_params #allows certain data to be passed via post form
    params.require(:post).permit(:user_id, :content)
  end
end
```

Comment: Try making an unsuccessful request to the create method.